# How to display arguments type label in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, editor, customization

I want the android studio to display a label next to the arguments of the methods like if its a **context** or **attachToRoot** as you can see in the image below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gWuU.png

How can I enable this option in Android studio?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a feature of Android Studio 3.0 and is enabled by default. It is still in Beta, but pretty stable. You may [try it now](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/index.html).

The settings & configuration is there

> File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Appearance -> Show parameter name hints